# How to handle 2 nested loops in the same li element without duplicates

Tags: arrays, symfony, twig

I have 2 variables arrays, one to show me the topics and the other to display the last post of each topic.
A post is repeated each time a topic is displayed. How to manage these 2 loops in the same element li

```
{% for lasttopic in lasttopics %}
   <li class="row bg2">                  
      <div class="list-inner">
         <a href="{{ path('showtopic', {'id': lasttopic.id}) }}" class="topictitle">
            {{ lasttopic.title }}
         </a><br />
      </div>
      {% for lastpost in lastposts %}
          Par <a href="" class="username">
                 {{ lastpost[0].user.username }}
              </a>
              <a href="" title="Go to last post" class="lastpost-last">
                 <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i>
              </a>
              <br />{{ lastpost[0].created|date('d/m/Y') }}
       {% endfor %}
   </li>
   <hr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: could you clarify the problem with a simple scenario (possibly with data?)

Comment: Is there any connection between a post and a topic? Obviously, you are looping over the same set of posts within the topic loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you for your answers. I solved my problem like this.

```
Add in Topic entity

public function countPosts()
{
    return count($this->posts);
}

public function lastPost() {
    return $this->posts[$this->countPosts()-1];
}

In Twig template

{% for lasttopic in lasttopics %}
   <a href="" class="topictitle">
      {{ lasttopic.title }}
   </a>
{% if lasttopic.countPosts > 0 %}
   <span>
      <a href="" class="username">
        {{ lasttopic.lastPost.title }}
      </a>
   </span>
   <span>
      <a href="" class="username">
        {{ lasttopic.lastPost.auteur.username }}
      </a>
   </span>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

In you controller, you can create two array : `lastTopics` and `lastPostByTopic[ID_TOPIC]`. Or merge the two tables into one multidimensional.

`Controller` :

```
[
    'topic' => Your topic object,
    'lastMessage' => Last message object
],
[
    'topic' => Your topic object,
    'lastMessage' => Last message object
],
[
    'topic' => Your topic object,
    'lastMessage' => Last message object
]
```

`Twig` :

```
{% for element in topics %}
    {{ dump(element.topic) }}
    {{ dump(element.lastMessage) }}
{% endif %}
```

Successive loops in Twig is not good. :)